# Is there a native alternative to the `watch` command; for Darwin/OS X

Tags: macos, compatibility, bash-scripting, bsd

I have a script that I'm trying to port from Linux to Darwin/OS X. The Linux version currently depends on the watch command, which doesn't appear to be installed on Darwin/OS X by default. What's the native alternative?

Answer (score 10):

There's no exact replacement. You could install the Linux `watch` command with your favorite package manager (homebrew or macports), or manually.

Or you could roll your own `watch`-like functionality with a small loop inside a shell function, like:

```
fakewatch () { while true; do clear; date; ${1}; sleep 2; done; }
```

Then call `fakewatch ps` (replace `ps` with whatever command you want to watch).

Answer (score 7):

Based on @Spiff awesome answer, I improved it a bit to avoid flickering/flashing on each execution:

```
fakewatch () { while true; do DATE=$(date); RESULT=$(${@}); clear; echo "$DATE"; echo "$RESULT"; sleep 5; done; }
```

This way, we store the result before printing it so at the time of printing everything gets printed at the same time

Answer (score 1):

This question [Is there a way to dynamically refresh the less command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4351/is-there-a-way-to-dynamically-refresh-the-less-command) might help.

For OS that doesn't support `watch` (like Darwin/OS X, Solaris),
you can try

```
less +F FILENAME
```

It's equivalent to pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> after `less FILENAME` which keep refreshing the file.

Comment: This is a neat solution. But I rejected your edit to the question to add “Solaris” to the question. Your answer might work for Solaris, but the question is focused on macOS and Darwin. And the fact this solution can be used on other OS’s like Solaris — and even Linux of one wanted to use it — doesn’t really matter much. This answer is great! But please do not attempt to change the author intent of the original question.

Comment: Make sense, thanks for your explanation.

Comment: If you use commands with parameters surround them by ""
for example for macOS:
`fakewatch "lsof -c syspolicyd"`

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to use homebrew package-manager.
See: [Homebrew](https://brew.sh)
If you have installed it, the way to go would be a simple:

```bash
brew install watch
```